# Java sockets file sending

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am writing Client/Server using java sockets. There is my code:

SERVER:

```
public void sendFile(File file) {
    BufferedOutputStreambufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    int count;
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        while ((count = in.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
            bufferedOutputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

CLIENT:

```
public void downloadFile() {
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    byte[] aByte = new byte[8192];
    int count;
    FileOutputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileOutputStream("C://fis.txt");
        while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(aByte)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(count); // <- nothing happens
            in.write(aByte, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Why bufferedInputStream in 2nd function is empty ?

Comment: What does this program print out? Also, can you add surrounding test code to make the example [complete](http://sscce.org/#co)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BufferedOutputStream` will not write data until the buffer is full. You need to flush the  `OutputStream`:

```
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
```

Comment: Thx. I didn't think about it.

Comment: flush pushes the bytes to OS buffers